# PHP not executing Python script

Tags: php

PHP is not executing my Python script and I don't understand why. The files are both in the same folder.

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $extracted = shell_exec("python script.py");
  $message = $extracted;
  echo $message;
?>
```

**Python**

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

**This is the error it gives me**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$message' (T_VARIABLE) in
> C:\Apache24\htdocs\server\test.php on line 3

It gives me a parse error, but I don’t see anything wrong with the code. It is not missing any semicolons.

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: @Henders I dont get how its a parse error. I'm not missing any semi-colons

Comment: this exact code worked in my system perfectly. got hello world.

Comment: @Henders Thats all the test.php file contains.

Comment: @Iceman What operating system are you on? I'm on windows 10

Comment: @RQ14 OSX ElCapitan 10.11.5 with php5.6.10

Comment: @Iceman do you think the problem could be with the operating system? Is the syntax a bit different?

Comment: There must be a non-printing character before `$message`. Look at the file with a hex editor.

Comment: @Ben He's getting a parse error, it's not running anything.

Comment: @Ben surely if it's a parse error, it won't run the PHP anyway so shell_exec() will never be run.

Comment: @RQ14 don't think so. Hope ur permissions are correct. but still shudnt show this error. r u sure you running the same code posted here?

Comment: @Barmar i did note something like that when i copy pasted.!!!

Comment: after the shell exec semicolon.

Comment: Could it be because I have both Python 2 & Python 3 installed? Do I need to specify in the exec command which python?

Comment: It's a parse error so the PHP script is not even running. The shell_exec() command doesn't ever get run in this case.

Comment: @Henders Why isn't it getting run? Is there something wrong with the command?

Comment: PHP cannot compile the script because the script you are attempting to run is not syntactically correct. The same way that something like `<?php ^ ?>` would cause you the same problem. PHP doesn't know what you are attempting to do. I'd go with @Barmar's suggestion.

Comment: This is really weird.. I just tried again without doing anything to the code and it worked...

Comment: The code, as posted here, does not contain any bytes above 128 (thus Unicode character sequences are ruled out).

Comment: There was a BOM at the end of this line `shell_exec("python script.py");` and it was removed by yourself at the first time you edited this question.